# I am getting error in docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am create a docker-compose yml file like this:-

```
version :'1.26' # specify docker-compose version

# Define the service/container to be run
services:
react: #name of first service
build: client #specify the directory of docker file
ports:
- "4200:4200" #specify port mapping

express: #name of second service
build: server #specify the directory of docker file
ports:
- "3000:3000" #specify port mapping
links:
- database #link this service to the database service

database: #name of third service
image: mongo #specify image to build contasiner flow 
ports:
- "27017:27017" #specify port mapping
```

But when I run the command I get an error:

```
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: expected '<document start>', but
found '<block sequence start>'
in "./docker-compose.yml", line 4, column 1".
```

How can I find the issue?

Comment: Please fix the indentation, it's significant in YaML.

Comment: Also your docker-compose `version` is _extremely old_. The [current version is 3.8](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) What version of Docker are you running?

Comment: But i am download it today and it shows me like this :-

Command :- sudo docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.26.0, build d4451659

Comment: That is the version of the `docker-compose` _binary_, not the version of the `docker-compose.yml` _file_. They are different things. Please see my link above.

Answer (score 2):

You have to fix space (between the version tag and version number) and indentation also i strongly suggest you to use a version 3+ of Docker-compose :

```
version: "3" # specify docker-compose version

# Define the service/container to be run
services:
  react: #name of first service
    build: ./client #specify the directory of docker file
    ports:
      - "4200:4200" #specify port mapping

  express: #name of second service
    build: server #specify the directory of docker file
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" #specify port mapping
    links:
      - database #link this service to the database service

  database: #name of third service
    image: mongo #specify image to build contasiner flow
    ports:
      - "27017:27017" #specify port mapping
```

Answer (score 1):

Your file is not valid YAML syntax, which is mainly defined by indentations (cf. [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html), for example). Try this:

```
version: '1.26' # specify docker-compose version

# Define the service/container to be run
services:
  react: #name of first service
    build:
      context: whatever
    ports:
      - "4200:4200" #specify port mapping

  express: #name of second service
    build:
      context: whatever
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" #specify port mapping
    links:
      - database #link this service to the database service

  database: #name of third service
    image: mongo #specify image to build contasiner flow 
    ports:
      - "27017:27017" #specify port mapping
```

However, you should probably have a look at some introductory material, like [the official docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/).

Answer (score -1):

I have found the issue. this is because yml file is indentation dependent.

i change my first line from **"version :'1.26'"** to **"version:'1.26'"**

Comment: Please note that you are still using almost certainly using the wrong compose file version.1.26 is the version of your `docker-compose` _binary_, not the version of the `docker-compose.yml` _file_. They are different things. Please see [the `docker-compose.yml` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/). 1.26 is not a valid version.